# Touchabble Opacity Not working-react native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

The touchableOpacity component doesn't work and I don't know why

The First Component App.tsx

```js
function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [focuseSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null)
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { focuseSubject ? <Text>{focuseSubject} </Text> : <Focus addSubject={setFocusSubject} /> }
      
      <Text style={ {color: 'white'} }>{ focuseSubject }</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The Second Component Focus.tsx

```js
function Focus({ addSubject }) {
    const [tempItem, setTempItem] = useState('');
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>What would you lie to focus on?</Text>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
                setTempItem(event.nativeEvent.text);
              }}
            />
            <RoundedButton
              title="+"
              size={50}
              onPress={() => {
                addSubject(tempItem);
              }}
            />
            {/* <Text>{ tempItem }</Text> */}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

The Third Component

```js
function RoundedButton({style = {}, textStyle = {}, size = 125, ...props}) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radios, style]}>
      <Text style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]}>
        {props.title}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

if I add `onSubmitEditing={addSubject(event.nativeEvent.text)}` it works fine but I want to use the button.

Note: `TouchableOpacity imported from react-native`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `onPress` props of `TouchableOpacity` from `RoundedButton`:

```js
function RoundedButton({style = {}, textStyle = {}, size = 125, ...props}) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radios, style]} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]}>
        {props.title}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you just made me feel dumb hehehe

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the passed props into the `<TouchableOpacity>` component.

```
function RoundedButton({style = {}, textStyle = {}, size = 125, ...props}) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={props.onPress}
      style={[styles(size).radios, style]}
    >
      <Text style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]}>
        {props.title}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```